# Insert a string at specified indexof position using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to insert the string " " or a blank space in a specified index on a textbox like so:

```
textbox = heybrowhatsup
```

I want to insert an " " on the indexes 4, 8 and 14, to get "hey bro whats up", but my code just won't work.

My code:

```
    Dim str As String = sum2.Text
    Dim insStr As String = " "
    Dim strRes As String = str.Insert(15, insStr)
```

Comment: You can continue with your solution as   Dim strRes As String = str.Insert(3, insStr).Insert(7, insStr).Insert(13, insStr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim str As String = sum2.Text
Dim insStr As String = " "
Dim strRes As String = str.Insert(3, insStr)
strRes = strRes.Insert(7, insStr)
strRes = strRes.Insert(12, insStr)
```

You must use `strRes.Insert` for second or more.

Comment: oh wait it didnt work... is it an import issue? ive recomplied and deleted the obj folder;

Comment: I think there are not any problem. What did you have problem?

Comment: Right i dont know why its not working, no errors are given during compile or on button click, but its not adding the instr(" "). any ideas?

Comment: i did about 12 characters and changed the inserts to 1, 2, and 3

Answer (score 1):

Any string manipulation creates a new `String` object.  What you're doing is working perfectly in that it is creating a new `String` with the specified substring inserted at the specified position.  As is always the case, if you want that `String` displayed in your `TextBox` then you must assign that `String` to the `Text` property of that `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

The Space function is useful for formatting output and clearing data in fixed-length strings.

You can use space function as below.

```
Dim str As String = "heybrowhatsup"
Dim strRes As String = str.Insert(3, Space(1)).Insert(7, Space(1)).Insert(13, Space(1))
```

Or

You can do the same with insert function.

```
 Dim str As String = "heybrowhatsup"
 Dim insStr As String = " "
 Dim strRes As String = str.Insert(3, insStr).Insert(7, insStr).Insert(13, insStr)
```